Shows Invalid URL After Clicking Download on Realtek Audio Driver
I am trying to download the Realtek Audio Driver from the official site (https://www.realtek.com/Download/List?cate_id=593&menu_id=369) due to audio issues following a recent Windows update. I plan to download the executable file for version R2.83.
However, after completing the CAPTCHA, I receive an error message stating: "Invalid URL or URL expired.(3)," despite providing the correct CAPTCHA response.
Could you please advise if there’s an alternative link or method to download and install the Realtek Audio Driver for my PC? Thank you!

Try another browser, try to clear the cache and download again.

Got the same problem with all RealTek downloads. With 3 different browsers under Win10. Finally I got it by calling the page from my samsung mobile with firefox. It downloaded a .txt File, but I seems, that only the ending was not correct. After rename the file I can open it and extract it.
